# Resize Box and Align not working on Long Equation

Tags: align, amsmath, split, resize, displaybreak

The following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sign}{sign}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\vast}{\bBigg@{4.5}}
\newcommand{\Vast}{\bBigg@{5}}
\makeatother

\title{Math Stack Question}
\author{bharathk98}
\date{May 2020}

\begin{document}

\maketitle   

\begin{align}
    \resizebox{.5cm}{!}
    {& $\lambda^{*}_{A}(S)=\\
    \inf\left\{\frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{m}\ell(I_{k,\epsilon})
    \bigl[1{-}\mu(A)(1{-}\mu(S\cap I_{k,\epsilon}))\bigr]\text{sign}(|A|)}
    {\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\ell(J_{k,\epsilon})
    \bigl[1{-}\mu(A)(1{-}\mu(A\cap J_{k,\epsilon}))\bigr]}:
 S\subseteq\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{m} I_{k,\epsilon}, A\subseteq\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{n} J_{k,\epsilon}, & \left|\lambda^{*}(S)-\sum\limits_{k=1}^{m}\ell(I_{k,\epsilon})\right|\le \epsilon,
    \\ & \left|\lambda^{*}(A)-\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\ell(J_{k,\epsilon})\right|\le \epsilon, 1\le m \le \max\left\{|S|,1\right\}, 1 \le n \le \max\left\{|A|,1\right\}; P = S\cap I_{k,\epsilon},
    \\ P= A\cap J_{k,\epsilon} \ \text{or} \ P= A; \mu(P)=\inf\left\{\text{sign}\left(\bigcup\limits_{s=1}^{t}G_s\right): P\subseteq \bigcup\limits_{s=1}^{t} G_s\right\}, 1 \le t \le \max\left\{|P|,1\right\} \right\}$}
    \end{align}

\end{document}
```

Returns an error. How do we fix this and number the equation? Note I used the following packages.

Comment: the `&` have to be at the top level so can not be in resizebox (and scaling math or text should be avoided in most cases anyway) simply remove the `\resizebox` here.

Comment: please always post complete small documents that show the problem, not disconnected fragments. In particular without an example that includes the page size it is hard to suggest any changes to make the equation fit in the page.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Made changes

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't compile as stated, in part because not all required packages are loaded, in part because it contains one or more syntax errors and a couple of entirely unnecessary `$` tokens.

Anyway, if I understood correctly what you're trying to get typeset, there's no need for a `\resizebox`-induced typographic calamity. Instead, just provide a few more linebreaks.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}

\DeclareMathOperator{\sign}{sign}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs\lvert\rvert
\newcommand\ddfrac[2]{\dfrac{\displaystyle #1}{\displaystyle #2}}
\begin{document} 

\begin{equation}
\lambda^{*}_{A}(S)=
\inf \ddfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{m}\ell(I_{k,\epsilon}) 
  \bigl[1-\mu(A)(1-\mu(S\cap I_{k,\epsilon}))\bigr]
  \sign(\abs{A})}{\sum_{k=1}^{n}\ell(J_{k,\epsilon})
    \bigl[1-\mu(A)(1-\mu(A\cap J_{k,\epsilon}))\bigr]}
\end{equation}
with
\begin{align}
& S\subseteq\bigcup_{k=1}^{m} I_{k,\epsilon},\  
  A\subseteq\bigcup_{k=1}^{n} J_{k,\epsilon}, \\
& \abs[\bigg]{\lambda^{*}(S)-\sum_{k=1}^{m}\ell(I_{k,\epsilon})}
  \le \epsilon,
\\ 
& \abs[\bigg]{\lambda^{*}(A)-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\ell(J_{k,\epsilon})}
  \le \epsilon,\\
& 1\le m \le \max\{\abs{S},1\},\ 
  1 \le n \le \max\{\abs{A},1\}; \\
&P = S\cap I_{k,\epsilon},\ 
 P = A\cap J_{k,\epsilon} \text{ or } P = A; \\
&\mu(P)=\inf\biggl\{ \sign\biggl(\,\bigcup_{s=1}^{t}G_s\biggr): 
P\subseteq \bigcup_{s=1}^{t} G_s\biggr\},\ 
 1 \le t \le \max\{\abs{P},1\} 
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This runs without error but I have no idea what layout you want, I suspect not this but it can be adjusted.
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sign}{sign}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\vast}{\bBigg@{4.5}}
\newcommand{\Vast}{\bBigg@{5}}
\makeatother

\title{Math Stack Question}
\author{bharathk98}
\date{May 2020}

\begin{document}

\maketitle   

\begin{gather}
    \lambda^{*}_{A}(S)=\\
    \inf\{\frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{m}\ell(I_{k,\epsilon})
    \bigl[1{-}\mu(A)(1{-}\mu(S\cap I_{k,\epsilon}))\bigr]\text{sign}(|A|)}
    {\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\ell(J_{k,\epsilon})
    \bigl[1{-}\mu(A)(1{-}\mu(A\cap J_{k,\epsilon}))\bigr]}: S
 \subseteq\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{m} I_{k,\epsilon},\\
 A\subseteq\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{n} J_{k,\epsilon},\\
|\lambda^{*}(S)-\sum\limits_{k=1}^{m}\ell(I_{k,\epsilon})|\le \epsilon,\\ 
|\lambda^{*}(A)-\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\ell(J_{k,\epsilon})|\le \epsilon, 1\le m \le \max\{|S|,1\},\\
 1 \le n \le \max\{|A|,1\};\\
 P = S\cap I_{k,\epsilon},\\
   P= A\cap J_{k,\epsilon} \ \text{or} \ P= A;\\
 \mu(P)=\inf\{\text{sign}(\bigcup\limits_{s=1}^{t}G_s): P\subseteq \bigcup\limits_{s=1}^{t} G_s\},\\
 1 \le t \le \max\{|P|,1\} \}
    \end{gather}

\end{document}
```